# SQL Timestamp offset (Postgres)

Tags: postgresql, input, pentaho

I want to copy records from one database to another using Pentaho. But I ran into a problem. Let's say there is a transaction_timestamp column ir Table1 with data type timestamp with time zone. But once I select records from the source DB and insert them into the other database - values of the column are offset by one hour or so. The weirdest thing - this doesn't even affect all records. I also tried something like this :

```
 select 
transaction_timestamp::timestamp without time zone as transaction_timestamp, 
t1.* from
table1 t1
```

And it didn't work. Could the problem be that when I copy the records to the 2nd DB, it sets all values to the local timezone? But why then the select statement I mentioned doesn't work? And only a part of the records is affected?

Comment: Data of type `timestamp with time zone` should stay the same when copied from one database to the other. Maybe they are the same, but the database servers have different `TimeZone` setting and the values are just displayed differently? Hard to say exactly unless you provide much more information.

Comment: Does it have something to do with DST (Daylight Savings Time)? I.E. does your source system have mixed time stamps flagged as DST? If you query the source in PG and convert the times to UTC, does the hour change?

Comment: This worked, thanks!